# How to locate elements (Shapes) in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

```
   private void DrawView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawView.ReorderMode = ListViewReorderMode.Enabled;
     var Location=   e.GetPosition(null);
     Node MyNode = new Node ();
     MyNode.Position.TranslateX = Location.X;
     MyNode.Position.TranslateY = Location.Y;

     GridPainter.Children.Add(MyNode.Circle);

} //Event that i am trying to use ,GridPainter is jut a Grid

public class Node
{
   public SolidColorBrush SelectedColor { get; set; }
   public Ellipse Circle { get; set; }
    public float XPosition { get; set; }
    public float YPosition { get; set; }
    public CompositeTransform Position { get; set; }
    public Node()
    {
        SelectedColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        Circle = new Ellipse {Fill=SelectedColor,Width=30,Height=30 };
        Position = new CompositeTransform();
        Circle.RenderTransform = Position;
    }

}//The class that i am using
```

What i would like to do, is draw a Ellipse in the point where the user tapped the screen, but for some reason my approach is not working. What am i missing?  Is this is even possible in C# code? This is my XAML code

```
<Page
x:Class="Graph_Painter.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Graph_Painter"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid x:Name="GridPainter" 
      Tapped="DrawVi`enter code here`ew_Tapped"
       IsTapEnabled="True" >

</Grid>
```

Comment: "is this even possible in XAML?" -- well, there's no XAML in your code example, so... But, yes...of course it must be possible to place a visual object at a point where a user has indicated, since each piece of the problem must itself be possible. A GUI would be pretty useless if it provided no way for the user to indicate a position, or to have no way to place a visual object. Absent [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to know why your code doesn't work, but maybe you aren't using the correct container and the shape is getting clipped.

Comment: It would help to see the XAML for the page

Comment: I just add the xaml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Canvas` is the better container for `Shapes`. Also, if just needs to modify `Left` and `Top` of visual shape consider use the `TranslateTransform` as `RenderTransform` property of the visual shape.

You can adapt the above code to your solution.

Partial XAML (The shapes container):

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas1"  Tapped="Canvas_Tapped" Background="White"/>
```

Code behind (Canvas tapped event handler):

```
private void Canvas_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetPosition(Canvas1);

    //example shape
    const double width = 30d;
    const double height = 30d;

    var ellipse = new Ellipse
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform
        {
            X = point.X - width/2,
            Y = point.Y - height/2
        }
    };

    Canvas1.Children.Add(ellipse);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: didn't work out.. for some reason it's not even activating the event :/

Comment: Well now it works out, i don't get it. All i have to do was change the background of my canvas to white and it work... Can you tell me why?

Comment: @fabiovides WPF panels like Grid and Canvas have a default Background that is `null`, which means that they don't get input events. You may however set `Transparent` as Background.